# Plot 3D (or spectrogram) from rtl_power input

Tags: plotting

I'm going to admit that I am a complete newbie when it comes to Wolfram Language (Dammit Jim, I'm a data analyst, not a mathematician!).

I have some output data from `rtl_power`, which is a utility to measure/detect signals using a software-defined radio.  The data output uses the following fields:

- **Date (yyyy-mm-dd)**
- **Time (hh:mm:ss)**
- Start of Range (in Hz)
- End of Range (in Hz)
- Step (in Hz, will always be 1000000.00 because I'm measuring in 1 MHz steps)
- Number of samples (always 1)
- **dbm at start of range**
- dbm at end of range (usually the same as the start of the range)

I've got it this far:

```
data = Dataset[ Import["/home/steven/data.csv"]];
datatable = 
 Table[<|timestamp -> FromDateString[data[i, 1] <> " " <> data[i, 2]],
    frequency -> Quantity[data[i, 3], "Hertz"], 
   dbm -> data[i, 7]|>, {i, Length[data]}];
```

The third step, `DateListPlot3D[datatable]`, is resulting in an empty chart.

Comment: If your data is equidistant in time and freq, try `ArrayPlot`, also see `DataRange` option for it

Comment: There is also a dedicated `Spectrogram` function

Comment: A lot of errors is produced, for example, "Import::nffil: File /home/steven/data.csv not found during Import." and "Dataset::dataextr: Data extraction failed." and "StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in Dataset[$Failed][1,1]<> <>Dataset[$Failed][1,2].".

Comment: I ended up converting the date/time to a UNIX timestamp and got it working with `ListDensityPlot`.